# PostgreSQL Privileges

Tags: postgresql, privileges

I have two databases on the same postgresql cluster. I want to restrict access to theses databases. below the scenario:

- *user_A* has full access to database *dbA*
- *user_B* has full access to dataabse *dbB*

I execute the following commands:

`revoke all on database _dbA_ from PUBLIC`

`revoke all on schema public from PUBLIC`

`revoke all on all tables in schema public from PUBLIC`

When I use command line, *user_B* can not connect nor display informations in database *dbA*. but using pgadmin4, *user_B* can access and display informations in *dbA*.

Could someone help fixing this issue?

[image]

Comment: Use [`pg_hba.conf`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/auth-pg-hba-conf.html) file

Comment: I used pg_hba.conf to set which users can access to which database. I do not have any problem from command line, when using psql. The problem is with pg_admin

Comment: With pgadmin user can display the contents of all tables in all databases. I revoked all permissions for olthers databases but still can access and display tables contents. Any idea?

Comment: If different connections let you access different data, it sounds like you are not using the same role or are not connected to the same database. Can you please run `SELECT session_user, current_user, current_catalog, current_schema;` in both command line and pgadmin and show us the results?

Comment: than you for your answer. I do not have any problem with command line. User b do not have any privilege on dbA. but with pgadmin, he can access and display content. when I execute your query, It show session_user=b, current_user=b, current_catalog=dbb on dbB andsession_user=a, current_user=a, current_catalog=dbA on dbA. but the question, why user B can connect to dbA?

Comment: Are you sure that `public` was the only user group containing `a` that has access to `dbA`? What do `\l` show in psql?

Comment: In your text, you say user_b can access dba.  But your image from pgAdmin4 is showing that it user_a is accessing dba, and that user_b is accessing dbb..

Comment: There is no much difference between pgAdmin and psql related to access to objects in the DB. If you can to do something via pgAdmin then you also can to do it via psql and vice versa. (Ok, I am dropped to use pgAdmin when it was transformed to webapp, but I believe that it still use libpq for connecting to the server)

Comment: Answer to jjnanes. In the picture I connected to database dbA as user A with password. after that I clicked on database dbB and I can display list of tables and contents. In command line if I use : psql -U a -d dba I connect to database dba but when I try to connect to database dbB with \c dbb I get "FATAL: permission denied for database "dbb". DETAIL: User does not have CONNECT privilege. Previous connection kept " \l display a list of database dba and dbb

Comment: I think I have problem with pgbouncer because pgadmin4 use pgbouncer to connect to database.